# How to enable remote desktop connection remotely [i need working variant]

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote

I need to enable Remote Desktop Connection remotely.I've been spending a lot of days on internet trying to find out how can i do it but, here i am, with my last hope i will solve it.I've been trying a lot of coommands and .vbs or .bat different scripts but none of them worked.

Here are some outputs:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>tasklist /svc | find "erm"
svchost.exe                   6520 TermService

C:\WINDOWS\system32>netstat -aon | find "3389"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       6520

C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh firewall set service remoteadmin enable
The service has not been started.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh firewall set service remotedesktop enable
The service has not been started.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

I even restarted the server after issueing:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v "fDenyTSConnections" /t REG_DWORD /d 0
```

Please,somone, come with a WORKING solution.

---

@surfasb: The version is: Microsoft Windows [Version 5.2.3790] 
@Conrad7: Remote Utilities is pretty nice, too bad i only have command line access.

By looking at the output i posted upper is clear that TermService is running, also port 3389 is opened and listening for connections?Am i missing something?Why i can't connect to the remote computer?

Comment: What version???

Comment: Why not use an alternative? Say, [Remote Utilities](http://www.remoteutilities.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for a server?

Have you checked to make sure port 3389 is forwarded properly to the server by any possible routers or intermediary devices on the server's LAN?

Have you checked the Event Viewer for any clues as to why those services won't start?  You can do so via the Windows command line by using [`wevtutil`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/li) or connecting via another machine on the server's LAN using `mmc eventvwr.msc`.

If this is an emergency I would [try installing VNC remotely](http://guh.nu/projects/vnc/) - I haven't tried it but it may be worth a shot and after you get VNC up you might be able to do more.

Comment: vnc remotely sounds pretty good.i'm gonna test it and give a reply.Thank you very much!

Comment: i tried install vnc remotelly, the installation succeeded:    WinVNC.exe                    4576 Console            0      2,972 K
also netstat showing that port 5900 is opened: 
C:\Program Files\vnc>netstat -a -n | findstr "5900"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5900           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
C:\Program Files\vnc>
firewall seems not to be running:
C:\Program Files\vnc>netsh firewall set opmode disable
The service has not been started.
C:\Program Files\vnc>netsh firewall set opmode enable
The Windows Firewall/Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) service is being started. .... bla bla
Ok.

Answer (score 0):

I just use the standard [Windows Desktop Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-allow-access) via [Tailscale](https://tailscale.com/), works fine.